# npm ERR! No versions available for stickme (NodeJS, NPM)

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

In my office project, stickme plugin is being used. It worked pretty well till the last week. However, now when I try to build the project, it seems to be failing.

Even if I try to install the stickme plugin manually (`npm install stickme`), it throws the below error.

```
npm ERR! code ENOVERSIONS
npm ERR! No versions available for stickme
```

**I tried:**

- Checking the npm website "https://www.npmjs.com/package/stickme?activeTab=readme" - it shows up 404
- Searching for stickme plugin - it shows "0 packages found"

Seems like the plugin / project might have been removed.

Is there any way I can install this manually (because it is already being used in my project and I can't switch to any other plugin now)

Comment: It's been [archived](https://github.com/mevbg/stickme) and unpublished.

Comment: No, because I'm not the person who did that.

Answer (score 0):

Its always best to not use unmaintained packages since you will run into issues later on. However, if you want to still use it, you can try installing it directly from github, instead of from NPM

Answer (score 0):

This issue was solved by updating the value of **stickme** property to "git+https://github.com/mevbg/stickme.git#semver:1.2.1" from **devDependencies** and **dependencies** in the package.json file